# Providing warnings and accuracy features on map for legal reasons

Tags: license

I work in a big corporation and one of my many responsibilities is making maps for field-workers. I usually make them very basic maps, as they know what infrastructure to look for, they just need the basic road directions, and they know what rate of accuracy our data is in. As a one-time assignment, My boss asked me to make a map for a new contractor and as one of the regular features is "dangerous places" (that the field workers should avoid) he said I should write a so-called legal comment on the map that states the user should not rely only on the map and to state the accuracy. And that got me thinking.

I know none of you are lawyers, and neither am I, but what do you do on your maps?

Right now, I only put the statement on "outside jobs".

Is that a mistake?

Should I put it also on "inside" jobs?

Do I have Individual responsibility and can be sued personally, or does my company "vouch" for me?

Answer (score 5):

**Map Disclaimers:**

*Information shown on these drawings/maps/charts is compiled from numerous sources and may not be complete or accurate.* 
(in 2 point font if possible).

*While the 'Big Corporation' and its suppliers have attempted to provide accurate information on our mapping, which we hope you find useful information will always be accurate and up to date.
The 'Big Corporation' cannot be held responsible for the misuse or misinterpretation of any information and offers no warranty guarantees or representations of any kind in connection to its accuracy or completeness.
The 'Big Corporation' accepts no liability for any loss, damage or inconvenience caused as a result of reliance on the mapping.* 
(in 3 point font)

Best Ever seen:

***Do NOT Trust this Map** (for skydiving or any other activity...)*

(12 BOLD font)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a disclaimer relating to "geospatial data products" that "appear to represent property boundaries", which is soon to be required by [law](http://www.legis.state.tx.us/tlodocs/82R/billtext/html/HB01147F.htm) in Texas:

> This product is for informational purposes and may not have been
>   prepared for or be suitable for legal, engineering, or surveying
>   purposes. It does not represent an on-the-ground survey and represents
>   only the approximate relative location of property boundaries.