# Advise on GPS logging for walking trails

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, android, garmin, hardware-recommendations

Context:
I am part of a volunteer organisation that needs to accurately log the GPS coordinates of walking trails.
They cover around 350km.
They are marked with waymarkers and signs, which we also want to record GPS for.

We would like a fast and easy way to log GPS accurately.
Specifically, record data every 2-5 meters for the trail routes and record locations of markers and signs on the trails.

We want as high accuracy as possible as the trails go near dangerous cliffs and other features.
In terms of official policy on accuracy required, 'reasonable' is the word used.

Questions:

1. If you have experience with this kind of GPS logging, what would you recommended as a convenient and cost effective solution in 2022?
2. There is also the possibility of using a surveyor's GPS (not sure of spec, but is worth several thousand euros).
   As far as I can tell this is overkill.
   Is there handheld device that is more accurate/reliable than the phone, but not at the surveyor price point?

My research so far suggests the Garmin GPSMAP® 66i, but it's €600 and I'm not sure if it will give more accurate/reliable GPS than just a Pixel 3a phone.
On the phone I use a free app called "GPS Logger".
If I want to follow GPS, I use QGIS to make kml/gpx files and open them with Google Earth on the phone.
It works well and it's free, but maybe there are nicer free things out there that I am not aware of.

Edit: I did reach out to Alltrails. They use our publicly available gps data to profit off of our volunteer work. They refused to provide help, but they would allow us to correct the incorrect information on their system for them, for free.

We decided that the phone GPS is good enough. I correct and edit the collected gpx files using JOSM. While not perfect, the results seem 'reasonable' in terms of accuracy.

Comment: You might consider including your trails in an existing system such as AllTrails, as the redundancy of use can be used to provide continually updated results. https://support.alltrails.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019244351-How-do-I-contribute-a-new-trail-to-AllTrails-

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, GIS SE is not a discussion forum where advice can be solicited.  We are a problem-solving site, using a Focused question/Best answer model.  While *opinion-based* questions are welcome in [Chat], it has a minimum reputation requirement, and it doesn't really see enough traffic to get the participation needed to make a well-rounded discussion. I suggest you seek a GIS discussion forum to ask these questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for my misunderstanding. Should I delete the post?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! If you can edit and make the post less opinion-based and focused it will be re-opened - it's certainly an interesting set of questions. Cellphone GPS can be excellent (but read up!), and an app like OSMTracker can be [customised](https://github.com/labexp/osmtracker-android/wiki/Custom-buttons-layouts) with buttons for points of interest (i.e. markers and signs) for rapid data collection along with tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overestimated your data requirements when you suggest you need to record points every 2-5 meters. The required number of data points is tied to the nature of the trail. On straight segments you only need one point at each end of the segment - all the intermediate points provide no additional information. The radius of curvature on curved segments determines the spacing. Handheld GPS units and smartphone GPS apps generally have a capability to record a track while hiking. The software dynamically chooses the spacing of the points depending on how the trail meanders. Over the past twenty years or so I've used Garmin handheld units (mainly map76csx) and more lately the Avenza maps app on an iPhone 6s+. On out-and-back hikes, the return path is virtually indistinguishable from the outbound path, even when zoomed in to see differences of just a few  meters or so.

If your intended use is for hikers to load your recorded trails on their GPS, remember that they will not be using a survey grade GPS, so the error of their unit will fuzz their position relative to your recorded data. No matter how accurate you are, there will always be issues. Of course, the more accurate your recorded tracks are, the better off the user will be, but unless you are recording data in areas with poor GPS reception, your tracks will almost certainly be "good enough", esp since you have described a trail network of well-marked, established trails. It sounds like a hiker should be able to follow these without a GPS, so even a rudimentary GPS track should be more than enough to aid the users of your trail system.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, and we'll use what we have already available. For future reference, the phone and 10 year Garmin are both good enough for what we want. There was a question about insurance regarding "accurately portraying the route", but the answer in our jurisdiction is that the phone/Garmin setup is good enough. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Where are you that there are standards for trail map accuracy? As litigious as the US is, I've never heard of someone suing for a poorly mapped route, let alone winning.

Comment: I'd prefer not to say where I am, but trail development groups have been sued here in the past for pretty crazy reasons. Not specifically for inaccurate maps, but it is a real possibility that someone will give it a try. Anyway, the solution seems to make sure we have visible disclaimers on our website and maps, and be able to show we have made 'reasonable' efforts to ensure their accuracy. Here's a post on this site talking about similar: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13514/providing-warnings-and-accuracy-features-on-map-for-legal-reasons)